# "git config --list" shows unexpected behaviour

Tags: github, terminal, macos-sierra

I am new to GIT. On using the following command the terminal window shows the following image and at the end of it my user name and Email. This is very different from the GIT Manual. Why is this happening?

```
git config --list
```

Output in the terminal

[image: Output Image]

Comment: I see many `Git Aliases`. e.g. you can type `git a` instead of `git add .; git status`. It's normal. Are you in trouble with this git config?

Comment: I entered my Name and Email and that seems to be working fine. Below the text in the above image it shows my Email Id and my Name. @sajibkhan

Comment: But why is it showing me so many aliases??

Comment: By any chance, you/other added this aliases manually or running any script? I think git doesn't add this automatically!

Comment: How do I solve this? I didn't do this since this is the first time I am configuring git on my laptop. Should I re-install GIT?

Comment: I  added an answer for editing your `git config list`

Answer (score 0):

#### `Answer` based on OP comment conversation:

Here, Many aliases got set in git config somehow. You can `unset` or `edit` your git config.

`--global` settings are saved in `~/.gitconfig` file.
`--local`  settings are saved in `<repsitory>/.git/config` file.

Open `~/.gitconfig` file using terminal or any editor. Now remove the line you don't want in your git config list.

#### `Unset` using a terminal command:

```
$ git config --global --unset core.quotepath   # remove your core 'quotepath'  
$ git config --global --unset alias.a          # remove your alias 'a'
```

#### `Remove` a whole section using terminal command:

```
$ git config --global --remove-section alias   # remove the 'global alias' section
$ git config --local --remove-section alias    # remove the 'local alias' section
```